# Confused about education assessment documents for ACS

Tags: visa, australia

I am really confused as I have done 3 years diploma in textiles and then 3 years degree in computers. For acs, I am giving degree certificate but my semester started from 3rd be cause of lateral entry so should I give diploma details as well?

Please help.

Comment: What is ACS? In general, I would give more, rather than less, information.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have your diploma chances are you will not get any points for it....

I would still submit copies of whatever paperwork you have from your teaching institution (I would even add textiles too...) get them notarised and send them across, worst that can happen they will not be 'deemed acceptable'...